# Were there established "denominations" for coins of different metals in ancient times?

Tags: ancient-history, currency

Nowadays, the value of a coin doesn't really have any relation to the value of its metal content. However, the earliest metal coins were presumably used because of their inherent value, being made of valuable metals like gold and silver. The relative value of gold and silver presumably varied over time (as it does now), as well as (I would guess) from place to place, depending on the relative availability of those resources.

My question is this: Were there standardized conversions between different types of coins? (A modern example is one nickel being equivalent to five pennies.) What is the history of this standardization, and how did people deal with fluctuating prices of precious metals?

Comment: Prior to the invention of fiat money, the value of a coin was related to the content of specie.  There were [specialists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_changer) who knew which countries coinage contained which amount of specie (or more properly were willing to bear the risk).

Comment: You should probably ask about a specific time and place, there have been thousands of types of currencies in human history. Wikipedia will give you a good overview for the better-studied civilizations.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I'm not really interested in a specific time or place, though. I'm asking about whether it happened at all, and, if and when it did happen, how it was dealt with. Mark's comment and link are pretty spot-on, except that the Wikipedia article has almost no information and I'm wondering about something *internal* to a civilization's economy, not about trade between groups with completely different coinage systems.

Comment: Wikipedia has 4,000 words on the topic of [Roman currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_currency), that doesn't seem like "almost no information."  If you specify which civilization you're interested in, someone can probably help; if all you want to know is "did coins have semi-fixed value ratios in any ancient societies?" I think the answer is clearly "yes."

Comment: Are you asking if there were subdivisions of coins, (i.e. Escudo, Peso, Peseta, Centimos) or if there were subdivisions of metal (gold piece, silver, copper), or both, or...

Comment: @CGCampbell Specifically coins of different metals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, denominational coinage, by definition, has a set relationship between the units and that relationship will not be exactly the same as the relative value of the metals involved. For example, the Roman denarius was originally denominated to be worth 10 asses. That's why it is called a "denarius" which means thing of ten.

This does normally cause a problem because the value of a coin is usually above its metal value because there is a value in the standardization and the authority of the issuer.

If, however, this seigniorage value is insufficient, then people will start melting the coins down, so in that case either the denominations need to be changed or the coinage needs to be debased (or upgraded). So, for example, the denarius was re-denominated to be worth 16 asses in 211 BC.